# Autotest responds slowly with Spork and Rspec under Rails 3.0.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, autotest, spork

It's all working, but slowly.

I know that Spork is working, because `rspec spec/` produces a response in under two seconds, and I know Autotest is working, since it eventually produces an appropriate Growl notification when I make a change to the controller code. The problem is that `Autotest` is taking too long to respond: about 16 seconds. Please help me figure out what's going wrong.

I'm new to Rails, and following Michael Hartl's Rails 3 Tutorial.

```
Platform:   Mac OS X 10.5.8
            Xcode 3.1.4
Ruby:       v. 1.9.2 p180  (with RVM)
Rails:      v. 3.0.9
```

*For what it's worth, I installed Autotest and Spork using Bundler, and call them (each under its own terminal window tab) using `bundle exec spork` and `bundle exec autotest`.  `spork` (without the "bundle exec") also runs fine, but `autotest` (without the "bundle exec") produces a "command not found" error message.*

My project's Gemfile (drawn from Hartl's tutorial book and video):

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.9'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'gravatar_image_tag', '1.0.0.pre2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  gem 'annotate', '2.4.0'
  gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.0.rc8'
  gem 'autotest', '4.4.6'
  gem 'autotest-rails-pure', '4.1.2'
  gem 'autotest-fsevent', '0.2.4'
  gem 'autotest-growl', '0.2.9'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
end
```

My project's .autotest file (also drawn from Hartl):

```
require 'autotest/growl'
require 'autotest/fsevent'
Autotest.add_hook :initialize do |autotest|
  autotest.add_mapping(/^spec\/requests\/.*_spec\.rb$/) do
    autotest.files_matching(/^spec\/requests\/.*_spec\.rb$/)
  end  
end
```

What happens:

When I save a change to one of my controller.rb files (or controller_spec.rb files), about 8 seconds elapse before there is any activity on the autotest terminal tab - which, at this point, is simply a row of hyphens preceded and followed by some empty lines.  About 7 seconds later, the autotest tab displays the following message:

`/Users/jlee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby -rrubygems -S /Users/jlee/rails_projects/sample_app_jbl/autotest/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/bin/rspec --tty '/Users/jlee/rails_projects/sample_app_jbl/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb'`

Which is followed almost immediately by activity on spork's terminal tab, and the expected results of the test in all terminal windows and in a growl notification.  So it's all working, just S-L-O-W-L-Y!  I'm eager for suggestions about how to cut the first fifteen seconds out of autotest's response.

8/7/2011

Comment: Have you same behaviour with ruby 1.8 or 1.9.2-head ? Can be the slow require problem

Comment: When autotest does finally respond, are you sure it's using Spork? (i.e. in the Spork terminal tab, are you seeing something like "Running tests with args...."?

Comment: Shingara:  I have only used Ruby 1.9.2-p180.  How can I determine if it is the "slow require problem"?
Dylan:  I am sure it's using Spork.  In the Spork terminal tab, it reads "Running tests with args ["--color", "--tty",  ... and the path to the controller_spec.rb file...]   
But that message doesn't come up until 15 seconds after I save the change to the controller file.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding --drb to the .rspec file at the root of your project: http://maxjustus.tumblr.com/post/1322305832/rspec-2-rails-3-autotest-and-spork

Comment: Thanks, John, but I've had --drb in the .rspec file in my project's root directory from the beginning.  I've pretty much given up on autotest.  I've had some luck with watchr, but the results have been unreliable so far.  For now, it's been easiest just to type rspec spec/ every time I want to run a test.

Comment: Incidentally, this was my issue, for what it's worth. Spork wasn't responding at all when autotest did its thing. It also wasn't doing anything when I ran `rspec spec`. Thanks!